# Rails select_collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view-helpers

I have smth like this: f.collection_select with options

I need to modify the standard behaviour of that collection_select (I need to add some option there)

Where should I do that?

I don't think this code is working, but you'll understand the idea

```
def collection_select(method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {}) 
  if options[:create_div] 
    return '<div>' + @template.collection_select(@object_name, method, collection, value_method, text_method, objectify_options(options), @default_options.merge(html_options)) + '</div>'
  end 
  @template.collection_select(@object_name, method, collection, value_method, text_method, objectify_options(options), @default_options.merge(html_options))
end
```

Comment: Please explain what's working so far, and which errors are you getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap it as a helper. You can use `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`

Comment: You don't need the @template variable in order to make a helper, could you post how are you definying the helper ?

Comment: I need to call the same standard method for creating select just to modify options before it (whether there are many options or just one etc.)

Comment: I don't think this code is working, but you'll understand the idea 
def collection_select(method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
        if options[:create_div]
          return '<div>' +    @template.collection_select(@object_name, method, collection, value_method, text_method, objectify_options(options), @default_options.merge(html_options)) + '</div>'
        end
        @template.collection_select(@object_name, method, collection, value_method, text_method, objectify_options(options), @default_options.merge(html_options))
      end

Comment: I don't recommend you to overwrite the default helper, put another name to your helper instead.

Comment: I need to do that, because collection_select is used all over the code. There is no possibility to modify views